# scroll to section by section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have HTML markup:

### HTML:

```
<body>
    <header></header>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#one">one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#two">two</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <section id="one"></section>
    <section id="two"></section>

    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

where **section is fullscreen** (width: 100%; height:100%;) and **menu** have **absolute position.**

### Question:

1. How can I use mouse scroll (or keys ) to scroll and snap to each section?
2. When scroll **to last** section then **scroll-down to #one** again and repeat it.
3. When I click on link, it scroll to section.

Thank you for your suggestions, ideas, code.

Comment: Check this plugin https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/continuous.html#firstPage

Comment: check this link out there is a new css property scroll-snap which you can use https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/

Answer (score 3):

Interesting

I stole [this code](https://codepen.io/vincentorback/pen/zxRyzj), changed the layout and tried to add the functions you mentioned (1. scroll-snap +  2. scroll when link is clicked).
Unfortunately, I can't have this second function to work.

1. Adding scroll-snap is not a problem

You need `scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;` on the container and `scroll-snap-align: start;` on the sections.

```js
var doc = window.document,
  context = doc.querySelector('.js-loop'),
  clones = context.querySelectorAll('.is-clone'),
  disableScroll = false,
  scrollHeight = 0,
  scrollPos = 0,
  clonesHeight = 0,
  i = 0;

function getScrollPos () {
  return (context.pageYOffset || context.scrollTop) - (context.clientTop || 0);
}

function setScrollPos (pos) {
  context.scrollTop = pos;
}

function getClonesHeight () {
  clonesHeight = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < clones.length; i += 1) {
    clonesHeight = clonesHeight + clones[i].offsetHeight;
  }

  return clonesHeight;
}

function reCalc () {
  scrollPos = getScrollPos();
  scrollHeight = context.scrollHeight;
  clonesHeight = getClonesHeight();

  if (scrollPos <= 0) {
    setScrollPos(1); // Scroll 1 pixel to allow upwards scrolling
  }
}

function scrollUpdate () {
  if (!disableScroll) {
    scrollPos = getScrollPos();

    if (clonesHeight + scrollPos >= scrollHeight) {
      // Scroll to the top when you’ve reached the bottom
      setScrollPos(1); // Scroll down 1 pixel to allow upwards scrolling
      disableScroll = true;
    } else if (scrollPos <= 0) {
      // Scroll to the bottom when you reach the top
      setScrollPos(scrollHeight - clonesHeight);
      disableScroll = true;
    }
  }

  if (disableScroll) {
    // Disable scroll-jumping for a short time to avoid flickering
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      disableScroll = false;
    }, 40);
  }
}

function init () {
  reCalc();
  
  context.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollUpdate);
  }, false);

  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(reCalc);
  }, false);
}

if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
  init()
} else {
  doc.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false)
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Loop {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

::scrollbar {
  display: none;
}


body {
  font-family: "Avenir Next", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

nav ul li{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav-link{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey
}

.one {
  background: black;
}
.two {
  background: darkblue;
}
.three {
  background: lightgreen;
}
.four {
  background: lightcoral;
}
.five {
  background: lightskyblue;
}
.six {
  background: orange;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 80px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#one">one</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#two">two</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#three">three</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#four">four</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#five">five</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#six">six</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main class="Loop js-loop">
  <section class="one" id="one">
    <h1>One</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="two" id="two">
    <h1>Two</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="three" id="three">
    <h1>Three</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="four" id="four">
    <h1>Four</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="five" id="five">
    <h1>Five</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="six" id="six">
    <h1>Six</h1>
  </section>

  <!--
  These blocks are the same as the first blocks to get that looping illusion going.
  You need to add clones to fill out a full viewport height.
  -->
  <section class="one is-clone">
    <h1>One</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="two is-clone">
    <h1>Two</h1>
  </section>

</main>
```

2. Adding the scrolling when you click on the link is a problem

With a normal container you only need to add the `scroll-behaviour: smooth;` to it. But here if you do that, you will lose the loop illusion because you will see it scroll **back** to the first instead of seemingly continue. (and it will also start an infinite back and forth scrolling that I couldn't fix yet)

```js
var doc = window.document,
  context = doc.querySelector('.js-loop'),
  clones = context.querySelectorAll('.is-clone'),
  disableScroll = false,
  scrollHeight = 0,
  scrollPos = 0,
  clonesHeight = 0,
  i = 0;

function getScrollPos () {
  return (context.pageYOffset || context.scrollTop) - (context.clientTop || 0);
}

function setScrollPos (pos) {
  context.scrollTop = pos;
}

function getClonesHeight () {
  clonesHeight = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < clones.length; i += 1) {
    clonesHeight = clonesHeight + clones[i].offsetHeight;
  }

  return clonesHeight;
}

function reCalc () {
  scrollPos = getScrollPos();
  scrollHeight = context.scrollHeight;
  clonesHeight = getClonesHeight();

  if (scrollPos <= 0) {
    setScrollPos(1); // Scroll 1 pixel to allow upwards scrolling
  }
}

function scrollUpdate () {
  if (!disableScroll) {
    scrollPos = getScrollPos();

    if (clonesHeight + scrollPos >= scrollHeight) {
      // Scroll to the top when you’ve reached the bottom
      setScrollPos(1); // Scroll down 1 pixel to allow upwards scrolling
      disableScroll = true;
    } else if (scrollPos <= 0) {
      // Scroll to the bottom when you reach the top
      setScrollPos(scrollHeight - clonesHeight);
      disableScroll = true;
    }
  }

  if (disableScroll) {
    // Disable scroll-jumping for a short time to avoid flickering
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      disableScroll = false;
    }, 40);
  }
}

function init () {
  reCalc();
  
  context.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollUpdate);
  }, false);

  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(reCalc);
  }, false);
}

if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
  init()
} else {
  doc.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false)
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Loop {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

::scrollbar {
  display: none;
}


body {
  font-family: "Avenir Next", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

nav ul li{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav-link{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey
}

.one {
  background: black;
}
.two {
  background: darkblue;
}
.three {
  background: lightgreen;
}
.four {
  background: lightcoral;
}
.five {
  background: lightskyblue;
}
.six {
  background: orange;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 80px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#one">one</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#two">two</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#three">three</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#four">four</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#five">five</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#six">six</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main class="Loop js-loop">
  <section class="one" id="one">
    <h1>One</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="two" id="two">
    <h1>Two</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="three" id="three">
    <h1>Three</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="four" id="four">
    <h1>Four</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="five" id="five">
    <h1>Five</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="six" id="six">
    <h1>Six</h1>
  </section>

  <!--
  This block is the same as the first block to get that looping illusion going.
  You need to add clones to fill out a full viewport height.
  -->
  <section class="one is-clone">
    <h1>One</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="two is-clone">
    <h1>Two</h1>
  </section>

</main>
```

I know this code is not 100% functional yet, but I think it can lead us to a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ID in this case.

Set the ID for your section and add anchor tag and set href attribute to your section id.

```html
<a href="#YourSectionID">Go Up</a> <!-- don't forget # before write your ID. -->
```

> Don't forget set scroll-behavior to smooth for smooth scrolling.