# jQuery Mouse scrolling entire windows every scroll, like aplle iphone5 website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Does any one know how can I set a scrolling of 100% of the window like in this website?

I have a website with a vertical scrolling, with every < div > set on li100% width and 100& height, i have an anchor system that allows me to scroll directly from a slide to another, using links on every < div  ID >

i would like to be able to do the same things with the mouse wheel,

http://www.apple.com/iphone-5c/

mine website:

http://www.mb.nullame.com/

Comment: One way could be to prevent scrolling by catching the event and do a preventDefault and there you trigger a translate3d for your own 'scrolling'... and on animationend you can do things like they do on the apple site...

Comment: do you have any link for to study how to "trigger a translate3d and create a my own scrolling"?

Comment: Apple iPhone 5S Website Like One Page Scroll Plugin For jQuery http://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Apple-iPhone-5S-Website-Like-One-Page-Scroll-Plugin-For-jQuery.html

Comment: I guess this site is not even scrolling - probably just mousewheel / toouchmove events are passed to js and it's supported fully by js - as you see there is no even scrollbar. probably it remembers last 'scroll' (modifies it on mousewheel events) position in js and animate site through 5 states using css classes changes or something like that

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134967/scroll-to-section-by-section/19141651#19141651

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of **[fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)**. It does exactly what you are looking for. Also, it is compatible with old browsers such as Internet Explorer 8, 9...

- [Demo](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)
- [Page](http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/fullpage-jquery-plugin-for-fullscreen-scrolling-websites/)

It is quite complete. You can add a menu, change the scrolling easing, the speed, use arrows to move, make it loop...

You can dowload it from the [github repository](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js).

Answer (score 0):

I'd make website body with absolute positioning 100% x 100% (to fill browser window) put into it div with real website content and disable scrolling (overflow hidden) then by listening to onmousewheel event (and touch events for touch devices) manage site - I'd make it as 5 sets of css rules for each 'frame' with transitions to make it look 'fluent'. In fact it can be played well with css - so you'd need in fact change only one class - class of this div with real site to 'scroll' it through viewport. Children elements could have parent dependent css like:

```
.pictureA{
  position:absolute;
  transition:all 0.5s;
}
.realBody_0 .pictureA{
  left:-50%;
}
.realBody_1 .pictureA{
  left:0;
}
```

and after let's say 5 mousewheel events change div with content class to realBody_1. (ofc count wheel up/down to properly manage it)